# Neo4j import tool fails and doesn't show why

Tags: neo4j

I have created 15.4 GB of csv files that I would like to import into fresh new Neo4j graph.db.
After executing `neo4j-admin import --delimiter="|" --array-delimiter="&" --nodes="processes.*"` command (I have 17229 csv files, that are named "processes_someHash.csv") I get this particular output:

```
..../pathWithCsvFiles: neo4j-admin import --delimiter="|" --array-delimiter="&" --nodes="processes.*"
WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
For input string: "10059167292802359779483"

usage: neo4j-admin import [--mode=csv] [--database=<name>]
                          [--additional-config=<config-file-path>]
                          [--report-file=<filename>]
                          [--nodes[:Label1:Label2]=<"file1,file2,...">]
                          [--relationships[:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE]=<"file1,file2,...">]
                          [--id-type=<STRING|INTEGER|ACTUAL>]
                          [--input-encoding=<character-set>]
                          [--ignore-extra-columns[=<true|false>]]
                          [--ignore-duplicate-nodes[=<true|false>]]
                          [--ignore-missing-nodes[=<true|false>]]
                          [--multiline-fields[=<true|false>]]
                          [--delimiter=<delimiter-character>]
                          [--array-delimiter=<array-delimiter-character>]
                          [--quote=<quotation-character>]
                          [--max-memory=<max-memory-that-importer-can-use>]
                          [--f=<File containing all arguments to this import>]
                          [--high-io=<true/false>]
usage: neo4j-admin import --mode=database [--database=<name>]
                          [--additional-config=<config-file-path>]
                          [--from=<source-directory>]

environment variables:
    NEO4J_CONF    Path to directory which contains neo4j.conf.
    NEO4J_DEBUG   Set to anything to enable debug output.
    NEO4J_HOME    Neo4j home directory.
    HEAP_SIZE     Set JVM maximum heap size during command execution.
                  Takes a number and a unit, for example 512m.

Import a collection of CSV files with --mode=csv (default), or a database from a
pre-3.0 installation with --mode=database.

options:
  --database=<name>
      Name of database. [default:graph.db]
  --additional-config=<config-file-path>
      Configuration file to supply additional configuration in. [default:]
  --mode=<database|csv>
      Import a collection of CSV files or a pre-3.0 installation. [default:csv]
  --from=<source-directory>
      The location of the pre-3.0 database (e.g. <neo4j-root>/data/graph.db).
      [default:]
  --report-file=<filename>
      File in which to store the report of the csv-i
... and more of a manual
```

What does the `For input string: "10059167292802359779483"` mean?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the headers in your CSV files? That's been a problem for me when importing previously.

Any chance your delimiter character is also appearing in data values?

Answer (score 0):

well, I tested neo4j importing with more compact dataset and it worked fine (when there was problem with delimiter for example, then the error message showed me what was the specific problem). I optimized my program for creating these csv files based on this low dataset and used it to make the mentioned bigger csv files, which doesn't work.